# Show/Hide Form on Radio Check

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I am trying to show the "individual" form and hide the "parent" form when the "individual" radio is checked, and show the "parent" form and hide the "individual" form when the parent radio is checked. My JavaScript function doesn't seem to be working, any ideas with what's wrong with it?

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Radio check 1 -->
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radios" id="radio1" onclick="radioCheck()" checked>
            Individual
        </label>
    </div>

    <!-- Radio check 2 -->

    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radios" id="radio2" onclick="radioCheck()">
            Parent of a child
        </label>
    </div>

    <!-- Form for individual -->
    <form id="individual">
        <!-- Individual's first name box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First name">
        </div>

        <!-- Individual's last name box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Last name">
        </div>

        <!-- Email box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <!-- Password box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>

        <!-- Individual's birthday --> 
        <label>Birthday</label>
        <select name="month" onChange="changeDate(this.options[selectedIndex].value);">
            <option value="na">Month</option>
            <option value="1">January</option>
            <option value="2">February</option>
            <option value="3">March</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">June</option>
            <option value="7">July</option>
            <option value="8">August</option>
            <option value="9">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
            <select name="day" id="day">
            <option value="na">Day</option>
            </select>
            <select name="year" id="year">
            <option value="na">Year</option>
         </select>

        <!-- Create account button -->
        <button></button>
    </form>

    <!--Form for child-->
    <form id="parent" class="hidden">
        <!-- Parent's first name box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Parent's first name">
        </div>

        <!-- Parent's last name box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Parent's last name">
        </div>

        <!-- Email box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>

        <!-- Password box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>

        <!-- Child's first name box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Child's first name">
        </div>

        <!-- Child's birthday -->
        <label>Child's Birthday</label>
        <select name="month" onChange="changeDate(this.options[selectedIndex].value);">
            <option value="na">Month</option>
            <option value="1">January</option>
            <option value="2">February</option>
            <option value="3">March</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">June</option>
            <option value="7">July</option>
            <option value="8">August</option>
            <option value="9">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
            <select name="day" id="day">
            <option value="na">Day</option>
            </select>
            <select name="year" id="year">
            <option value="na">Year</option>
        </select>
        <!-- Create account button -->
        <button></button>
    </form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#individual {
    display: block;
}

#parent {
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function radioCheck() {
    var radio1 = document.getElementById("radio1");
    var radio2 = document.getElementById("radio2");
    var individual = document.getElementById("individual");
    var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
    if (radio2.checked == true){
        individual.style.display = "none";
        parent.style.display = "block";
    } 
    else {
        individual.style.display = "block";
        parent.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: first you have to close all input tag `<input/>` with `/`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake, I appreciate it and have fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since one of your radio button is selected by default you have to call or invoke `radioCheck()` on page load. And also do not forget to close all of your `input` elements.

```js
function radioCheck() {
    var radio1 = document.getElementById("radio1");
    var radio2 = document.getElementById("radio2");
    var individual = document.getElementById("individual");
    var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
    if (radio2.checked == true){
        individual.style.display = "none";
        parent.style.display = "block";
    } 
    else {
        individual.style.display = "block";
        parent.style.display = "none";
    }
}
radioCheck()
```

```html
<!-- Radio check 1 -->
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radios" id="radio1" onclick="radioCheck()" checked/>
        Individual
    </label>
</div>

<!-- Radio check 2 -->

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radios" id="radio2" onclick="radioCheck()"/>
        Parent of a child
    </label>
</div>

<!-- Form for individual -->
<form id="individual">
    <!-- Individual's first name box -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First name"/>
    </div>

    <!-- Individual's last name box -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Last name"/>
    </div>

    <!-- Email box -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    </div>

    <!-- Password box -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>

    <!-- Individual's birthday --> 
    <label>Birthday</label>
    <select name="month" onChange="changeDate(this.options[selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="na">Month</option>
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>
        <select name="day" id="day">
        <option value="na">Day</option>
        </select>
        <select name="year" id="year">
        <option value="na">Year</option>
     </select>

    <!-- Create account button -->
    <button></button>
</form>

<!--Form for child-->
<form id="parent" class="hidden">
    <!-- Parent's first name box -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Parent's first name"/>
    </div>

    <!-- Parent's last name box -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Parent's last name"/>
    </div>

    <!-- Email box -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    </div>

    <!-- Password box -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>

    <!-- Child's first name box -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Child's first name"/>
    </div>

    <!-- Child's birthday -->
    <label>Child's Birthday</label>
    <select name="month" onChange="changeDate(this.options[selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="na">Month</option>
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>
        <select name="day" id="day">
        <option value="na">Day</option>
        </select>
        <select name="year" id="year">
        <option value="na">Year</option>
    </select>
    <!-- Create account button -->
    <button></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree ,First you have to close all the input tags.

But the code in question is working fine for me without any changes:

```
<script>
function radioCheck() {
    var radio1 = document.getElementById("radio1");
    var radio2 = document.getElementById("radio2");
    var individual = document.getElementById("individual");
    var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
    if (radio2.checked == true){
        individual.style.display = "none";
        parent.style.display = "block";
    } 
    else {
        individual.style.display = "block";
        parent.style.display = "none";
    }

}
</script>
<!-- Radio check 1 -->
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radios" id="radio1" onclick="radioCheck()"  />
            Individual
        </label>
    </div>

    <!-- Radio check 2 -->

    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radios" id="radio2" onclick="radioCheck()"/>
            Parent of a child
        </label>
    </div>

    <!-- Form for individual -->
    <form id="individual" style="display:none">
        <!-- Individual's first name box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First name"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Individual's last name box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Last name"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Email box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Password box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Individual's birthday --> 
        <label>Birthday</label>
        <select name="month" onChange="changeDate(this.options[selectedIndex].value);">
            <option value="na">Month</option>
            <option value="1">January</option>
            <option value="2">February</option>
            <option value="3">March</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">June</option>
            <option value="7">July</option>
            <option value="8">August</option>
            <option value="9">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
            <select name="day" id="day">
            <option value="na">Day</option>
            </select>
            <select name="year" id="year">
            <option value="na">Year</option>
         </select>

        <!-- Create account button -->
        <button></button>
    </form>

    <!--Form for child-->
    <form id="parent" class="hidden" style="display:none">
        <!-- Parent's first name box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Parent's first name"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Parent's last name box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Parent's last name"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Email box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Password box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Child's first name box -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Child's first name"/>
        </div>

        <!-- Child's birthday -->
        <label>Child's Birthday</label>
        <select name="month" onChange="changeDate(this.options[selectedIndex].value);"/>
            <option value="na">Month</option>
            <option value="1">January</option>
            <option value="2">February</option>
            <option value="3">March</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">June</option>
            <option value="7">July</option>
            <option value="8">August</option>
            <option value="9">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
            <select name="day" id="day">
            <option value="na">Day</option>
            </select>
            <select name="year" id="year">
            <option value="na">Year</option>
        </select>
        <!-- Create account button -->
        <button></button>
    </form>
```